# Get random Redis key greater than x

Tags: redis

I understand that the command 'RANDOMKEY' returns a random key from the currently selected Redis database.

However, assuming all key values are numeric, how do I get a random key that has a value greater than zero?

Comment: This is really not what this command (or redis) is for. You can, however, do something in Lua.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use RANDOMKEY for that, but you could use a Redis Set for that.

For every non-zero key that you set in the database, add that key's name to a set. For example, let's say your key is:

```
SET foo 1
```

Follow that command with something like:

```
SADD nonzeros foo
```

Assuming you SADD every non-zero key name to the set named `nonzeros`, you can get a random key name by doing:

```
SRANDMEMBER nonzeros
```

And then do GET for that key.